# How to I calculate permutations without memory problems

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I need all permutations of a List l = [1,2,...,n] with length m.

```
from itertools import permutations
def calcPerm(l:list,m: int)
    perm=[]
    for i in permutations(l, m):
        perm.append(list((i)))
```

But like u see for n great enough the memory will explode.

Is there a way where I do not have to save does permutations, so i can use every single one
immediately but not get them twice( e.g [1,2] and [2,1] ?

Comment: It using `calcPerm` as a generator an option for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `combinations` instead of `permutations`:

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations
my_list = [1,2,3]
print(list(permutations(my_list, 2)))
#[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]

print(list(combinations(my_list, 2)))
#[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.combinations` and to save memory use `yield`:

```py
from itertools import combinations


def calcPerm(l: list, m: int):
    for i in combinations(l, m):
        yield list((i))


for p in calcPerm(range(10), 5):
    print(p)
```